# pandas assign with whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use pandas `.assign()` with a column name which consists of whitespaces.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Website': {0: 'm.google.com', 1: 'uk.search.yahoo', 2: 'us.search.yahoo.com', 3: 'google.co.in', 4: 'm.youtube', 5: 'youtube.com'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# works
df.assign(test=1)

# raies error
df.assign(whitespace test=1)
df.assign('whitespace test'=1)
df.assign({'whitespace test': 1})
```

I am aware of:

```
df['whitespace test'] = 1
```

but I want to understand how to solve it with `.assign()` (if possible).

Comment: Unpack that dictionary: `df=df.assign(**{'whitespace test': 1})`

Comment: @AnuragDabas, you had the same question? what a coincidence. ty